# How to setup initial Electron Angular project

Tags: angular, electron

How can I setup initial Electron project with Angular4, I want to start with TypeScript for with both of these, any guideline will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this boilerplate [Angular-Electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron), It is setup with electron with UI in Angular.